# Solr closes connection to Zookeeper

Tags: tcp, solr, apache-zookeeper

I have two servers, server one running apache zookeeper and server two running Solr.
When starting the zookeeper I can connect to it on server one (through bin/zkCli.sh) but not through server two with solr.
Zookeeper is started through `supervisor`, but I have also tried starting it through `bind/zkServer.sh` without improvements.
When looking in the tomcat log (which Solr is logging to) I get:

```
WARNING: Overseer cannot talk to ZK
Jun 04, 2013 3:26:52 PM org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer$ClusterStateUpdater amILeader
WARNING:
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /overseer_elect/leader
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$7.execute(SolrZkClient.java:253)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$7.execute(SolrZkClient.java:250)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:65)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.getData(SolrZkClient.java:250)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer$ClusterStateUpdater.amILeader(Overseer.java:199)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer$ClusterStateUpdater.run(Overseer.java:122)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

...


Jun 04, 2013 3:31:04 PM org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread logStartConnect
INFO: Opening socket connection to server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
Jun 04, 2013 3:31:04 PM org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread run
INFO: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 46974ms for sessionid 0x13f0f5a570c0006, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
Jun 04, 2013 3:31:05 PM org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread logStartConnect
INFO: Opening socket connection to server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.75:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
Jun 04, 2013 3:32:01 PM org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread run
INFO: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 56627ms for sessionid 0x13f0f5a570c0006, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

How do I setup zookeeper such that it can be accessed by solr on server two?

Additional info: Using `netstat -l` on server one, I get the following:

```
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2181               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I.e. it is only listening on tcp6, not tcp.

Answer (score 0):

Check you firewall configuration on the zookeeper server and ensure port 2181, 2888 and 3888 are all open.  2181 is the client communication port, 2888 and 3888 are used for zookeeper cluster communication (in case you decide to run zookeeper in an ensemble).